# Embedded Compact 2013 SMB V 2.0 or V 3.0

Tags: share, windows-ce, smb

Can Embedded Compact 2013 access SMB V2.0 file shares? 
Google has not found anything.

Walter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, there is an external SMB lib that you can integrate into you embedded compact 2013 , the lib is called YNQ by Visuality Systems , check the product [website](https://www.visualitynq.com/products/ynq).

The other choice is to upgrade to Windows 10 IoT , this is the newest windows embedded OS and it does support SMB connection.

Comment: I need this for a finished product https://www.beijerelectronics.com/box2, so updating to Windows 10 IoT is not possible. But it seems YNQ may work.